# Determine the encryption algorithm of Post request from mobile application to API

Tags: encryption, hash, rsa, sha256

I'm trying to understand how does a mobile application encrypt the password when I submit a POST request from mobile application to API
so that I can make a python code that can use the same algorithm to a send a encrypted password to the API same as the mobile app.

I tired to catch a private API of an mobile App, I got the request where the application send the request, but what is funny here is the application is encrypting the password before it send it via POST request to API this is how the password looks in the request:

`password=GmdKoBhIne4g3KR8JeR/Cg==`

the mobile app is encoding the password that I already know the password when it sent a request to API, but what I want is to catch the way this mobile application is encrypting the password, the encryption type is not Base64 (for sure lol), I tired to sent a request to API without the encryption, and I got an error. which means the API is decrypting the password.

So I tired to decompiled the mobile app, and I got the source code, it was trouble, the code source was complex and with random functions names which made it very hard to read lol, variables are randomly generated after I decompiled the apk.

[image]

So I tired to search in the code source for keywords like ( password, API.....), and finally I got a line where I can to start,
I'm trying to catch how does the mobile application convert a password string to an unknown encryption type, before 2 days I decompiled an APK file but the encryption is still hard to catch :(
I found this:

[image]

and the function returns :

```
if (str21 != null) {
        i = str21.hashCode();
    }
return hashCode23 + i;
```

but still can't understand nothing from the encryption algorithm :(

I was searching on the code source and I found two files CERT.SF & CERT.RSA
I don't know but I feel that those two files can help me, the CERT.SF file include many SHA-256-Digests and the RSA I can't read it.

I tired to test alphabets in the form where I post the request on the app, for example :
I though that I can catch letters like (A, B, C..... 1,2,3....)
but when I post A, I received on Burp-suite that the password is generated again to a random string like before so nothing changed

If someone with a cryptography can help me to solve this may be Amazing <3

Thanks.

Comment: Software reverse engineering is hard-work and you have a good start. Unfortunately none of the code you've shown seems to provide much of a clue as to how the password is encrypted.

Comment: After surfing on the code source I found that the app is using RSA to encrypt the password, If you have an idea about it we can discuses about that on private.

Comment: Since the encrypted password is only 16 bytes it is very unlikely that RSA is being used.

Comment: there is two files CERT.SF && CERT.RSA // also I saw publicKey and privateKey a lot on the code source:   instance.init(1, (RSAPublicKey) publicKey);

Comment: The CERT files are related to signing the application,, may nothing to do with encrypting the password. The question and code in it provides no useful information to answer it.

Comment: @gusto2 I found your twitter, I saw your amazing work on WordPress, can we have a chat? to discuses this with you? thanks

Comment: Looks like that app is an Android app, correct? If yes you can try to install the app on a rooted device/emulator and hook all crypto methods using frida/objection. If the app uses the crypto algorithms provided by Android (hence uses real crypto and not just something self-developed) then tracing the crypto methods will show you input, key and encrypted output.

Comment: @Robert thanks robert, I already solved it. I used Frida and a custom code python to trace the PID of mobile app, thanks

Comment: Then you can answer your own question. Provide a nice description so that other can learn from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, thanks of some Chinese articles that help me to figure out this.

the mobile application was Obfuscated, but thanks god I found some traces of that the app was using **AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding**, so I jumped up and I rooted my device and I bypass SSL panning and I installed the friendly **Frida** server on my device shell, and I got the PID of the mobile application, I found many scripts that help to detect secret keys on the mobile but no script was working. So I tired to understand how does Frida can detect the secret keys, and I coded a custom python script that scraps keys from the mobile app.
for the custom python script I can't share because It includes the mobile app functions that I'm pretesting on it.
but I can help with some sources to understand how does Frida can bypass the cipher algorithm

Frida : https://github.com/frida/frida

Exploit code : https://github.com/Kc57/blog_post_code/tree/master/frida-python-bindings-example